# Minikube Ingress address empty - Mac

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, nginx-ingress

I added a deployment with:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      name: nginx-pod
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx-container
          image: nginx:alpine
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

And service with:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - port: 8082
      targetPort: 80
```

Here is my ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: nginx-testing.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: nginx-service
                port:
                  number: 8082
```

Before running this I ran:

```
minikube addons enable ingress -p my-cluster
```

But when I do **kubectl get ingress** address is empty

[image]

[image]

here are the ingress controller pod logs:

```
E1103 11:01:57.070385       7 leaderelection.go:361] Failed to update lock: configmaps "ingress-controller-leader" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:ingress-nginx:ingress-nginx" cannot update resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "ingress-nginx"
```

Am I missing anything here?
I'm trying the basic ingress rule but it's not working.

Can someone help me here, please?

**EDIT 1:**

Here is the role:

```
test % kubectl get Role -n ingress-nginx -oyaml ingress-nginx
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1","kind":"Role","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/component":"controller","app.kubernetes.io/instance":"ingress-nginx","app.kubernetes.io/name":"ingress-nginx"},"name":"ingress-nginx","namespace":"ingress-nginx"},"rules":[{"apiGroups":[""],"resources":["namespaces"],"verbs":["get"]},{"apiGroups":[""],"resources":["configmaps","pods","secrets","endpoints"],"verbs":["get","list","watch"]},{"apiGroups":[""],"resources":["services"],"verbs":["get","list","watch"]},{"apiGroups":["extensions","networking.k8s.io"],"resources":["ingresses"],"verbs":["get","list","watch"]},{"apiGroups":["extensions","networking.k8s.io"],"resources":["ingresses/status"],"verbs":["update"]},{"apiGroups":["networking.k8s.io"],"resources":["ingressclasses"],"verbs":["get","list","watch"]},{"apiGroups":[""],"resourceNames":["ingress-controller-leader"],"resources":["configmaps"],"verbs":["get","update"]},{"apiGroups":[""],"resources":["configmaps"],"verbs":["create"]},{"apiGroups":[""],"resources":["events"],"verbs":["create","patch"]}]}
  creationTimestamp: "2021-11-03T12:29:32Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  resourceVersion: "2487"
  uid: e140ea8f-04a5-4bf2-9e26-9803d581f608
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - get
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmaps
  - pods
  - secrets
  - endpoints
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - services
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingresses
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingresses/status
  verbs:
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingressclasses
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resourceNames:
  - ingress-controller-leader
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs:
  - get
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs:
  - create
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - events
  verbs:
  - create
  - patch
```

Comment: `minikube service list` should show you the address.

Comment: No @YK1 It's not showing. Added screenshot in the description

Comment: What is the output of `k get IngressClass` and, if there are any entries, a describe of it?

Comment: @AndD `No resources found` for IngressClass

Comment: I'm not really an expert of using minikube. Either the address will not be shown but the ingress is taken into consideration (check the Nginx Ingress Controller Pod logs to see if it says that it is now serving your Ingress) or the Ingress misses an ingress class.. but checking minikube guides I found nothing regarding that.. so probably it is not necessary on minikube.

First thing first, I would check nginx ingress controller logs, can you post them?

Comment: @HealthyBowl, please include logs in your original question. Pasting links to external sites is not recommended, since this information may be removed from external service, and will be unavailable in the future. Also, please don't post textual data as images. Read [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Logs indicate the service account `ingress-nginx` does not have sufficient privileges in `ingress-nginx` namespace. Do you have any Roles/ClusterRoles and RoleBindings/ClusterRoleBinding for this service account?

Comment: No @p10l. What roles should I add?

Comment: Check Roles, Service Accounts and Bindings with `kubectl get Role,RoleBinding,ServiceAccount -n ingress-nginx`. If there are objects, check the Role description.. you may need to add permission to edit configmaps

Comment: @AndD if you don't mind, can you please the kubectl command for that?

Comment: Something like the following `k get Role -n ingress-nginx -oyaml ingress-nginx`, if the Role is called `ingress-nginx`. Also, like @p10l suggested, include the new content in the original question as text. Just edit it up and add logs or definitions as code

Comment: Added the role output in the description @AndD. Can you tell me what we need to add?

Comment: I tried ```minikube tunnel -p ingress-cluster``` also @AndD and @p10l . But no luck

Comment: Most likely something to do with your networking setup and minikube driver, what is output of `minikube ip`, do you have IP assigned ?

Comment: @HealthyBowl the Role looks ok to me, it seems very similar to the one in my test cluster (which is not minikube so there are slight differences but nothing major)

Comment: Yes @YK1 `minikube ip` has IP assigned

Comment: Which version of minikube are you using? Check it with `minikube version`

Comment: minikube version: v1.23.0 @p10l

Comment: As @AndD suggested (their comment is now deleted) there is a bug in minikube 1.23.0 [#12445](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/12445). Solution is to upgrade minikube to 1.23.1, or 1.24. AndD, do you want to post an naswer? If not, I'll post a CW.

Comment: Hi @p10l Thank you so much. After upgrading to 1.24.0, address is assigned as `localhost`. And I added an entry in `/etc/hosts` as `127.0.0.1 hello-world.info`. When I try to access `curl hello-world.info` It's not able to reach. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: *hello-world.info* is already a registered domain [whois lookup](https://who.is/dns/hello-world.info), I'd strongly recommend against using it for testing/development purposes. Using `/etc/hosts` file is outside of the scope of this question. We should keep this focused on a single topic.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found by another community member in the comments (their comment is now deleted), hence the CW.

---

There is a bug in minikube *1.23.0*: [NGINX Ingress addon Role resource references incorrect ConfigMap #12445](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/12445)

Solution is to upgrade minikube to *1.23.1*, or *1.24*.